# rails 7.0.4 Unknown validator: DateValidator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This line of code in my rails 7 model causes the error "Unknown validator: DateValidator" It was working in rails 6

```
validates :showdate,   :date => { :after => Time.now + 2.hour }, :if =>  Proc.new { |e| e.user_id.present? }
```

Answer (score 2):

In rails 7 there is [ComparisonValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40095) and you can use it like so:

```
  validates :showdate, comparison: { greater_than: Time.now + 2.hour }
```

or

```
  validates_comparison_of :showdate, greater_than: Time.now + 2.hour
```